# delphi, send image with indy10 from client to server

Tags: delphi, sockets, tcp, indy10

How I can send from a Timage (clientside) to another Timage(serverside)?
I'm using delphi XE3 with idtcpclient1, idtcpserver1 (indy10 component).
I already tried to do something but I had some trouble.

**Server side:**

```
FileStream := TFileStream.Create('ciao.jpg', fmCreate);
AContext.Connection.IOHandler.LargeStream := True;
AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadStream(FileStream); FileStream.Free;
image1.Picture.LoadFromFile(sname);
```

**Client side:**

```
idTCPClient1.IOHandler.LargeStream := True;
FileStream := TFileStream.Create('hello.jpg', fmOpenRead);
IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.Write(FileStream,0,true);
filestream.Free;
```

Comment: "I already tried to do something but i had some trouble". What did you try to do, and what trouble did you have? Please [edit] your post and show us what you've tried so far that isn't working for you.

Comment: i worked with file, i send a file and i open it, and i need a method how to bypass this step, now is: Timage(client)->file->stream->file->Timage(server)

Comment: and i want Timage(client)->stream->Timage(server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is unclear, but it seems that you're trying to transfer the content of one 'TImage' (on the client) to a `TImage` on the server. It's unclear whether you mean an *image file* or an actual `TImage`, though. I'm going to go with "the picture being displayed in a TImage on the client" being sent to the server. 
You can use `TMemoryStream` instead of `TFileStream`. If you really mean to send the image displayed in a `TImage.Picture`, you can do something like this (untested):

```
// Server side
var
  Jpg: TJpegImage;
begin
  Strm := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    Strm.Position := 0;
    AContext.Connection.IOHandler.LargeStream := True;
    AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadStream(Strm);
    Strm.Position := 0;
    Jpg := TJpegImage.Create;
    try
      Jpg.LoadFromStream(Strm);
      Image1.Picture.Assign(Jpg);
    finally
      Jpg.Free;
    end;
  finally
    Strm.Free;
  end;
end;

// Client side
IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.LargeStream := True;
Strm := TMemoryStream.Create;
try
  Image1.Picture.Graphic.SaveToStream(Strm);
  Strm.Position := 0;
  IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.Write(Strm, 0, True);
finally
  Strm.Free;
end;
```

If that's not what you want, **edit your question** so we can understand what you're trying to do. (Don't tell us in comments, but actually edit your question to make it more clear.)

Comment: your answer is good and what i needed! i will test it, sorry for my bad question

Comment: i had an error during `Image1.Picture.Graphic.LoadFromStream(Strm);` _i had acces violation at address 00b85e1a... read of address 0000000_

Comment: That's because you never had one assigned before it. I'll edit to provide a solution.

Comment: Your example will only work if `Image.Picture.Graphic` is a `TJPEGImage` on the client side, since `TJPEGImage` is being used on the server-side. If you need to support multiple image formats, then the client will have to specify which format it is transmitting so that the server can create an instance of the appropriate `TGraphic` class for it.

Comment: Remy, the posted code in the original question specifically used JPEG images on both the client and server sides. I answered the specific question asked. If the poster has an additional question about how to transfer different format images and display them, that would be an additional question. :-)

Answer (score 4):

Example implementation for the transfer of different graphic formats.

Main issue is that you will have to create an appropriate GraphicClass.
If an image is loaded from a file the class is determinate from the file extension.
In this implemetation we add the information to the stream.

```
unit Unit1;
interface
uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, IdContext, Vcl.ExtCtrls, IdTCPConnection, IdTCPClient, IdBaseComponent,
  IdComponent, IdCustomTCPServer, IdTCPServer, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.Imaging.jpeg;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    IdTCPServer1: TIdTCPServer;
    IdTCPClient1: TIdTCPClient;
    Source: TImage;
    Dest: TImage;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private-Deklarationen }
  public
    { Public-Deklarationen }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation
uses PNGImage;

{$R *.dfm}

//Enable transfer of different graphicformats

procedure Picture2Stream(DestStream: TMemoryStream; Picture: TPicture);
var
  ms2: TMemoryStream;
  TheClassName: AnsiString;
  len: Byte;
begin
  TheClassName := Picture.Graphic.ClassName;
  len := Length(TheClassName);
  DestStream.WriteBuffer(len, 1);
  if len > 0 then     // save GraphicClass name
    DestStream.WriteBuffer(TheClassName[1], len);
  ms2 := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try                // save graphic
    Picture.Graphic.SaveToStream(ms2);
    ms2.Position := 0;
    if ms2.Size > 0 then
      DestStream.CopyFrom(ms2, ms2.Size);
  finally
    ms2.Free;
  end;
end;

Procedure LoadPictureFromStream(Picture: TPicture; SourceStream: TMemoryStream);
var
  ms2: TMemoryStream;
  len: Byte;
  TheClassName: AnsiString;
  Graphic: TGraphic;
  GraphicClass: TGraphicClass;
begin
  SourceStream.Position := 0;
  SourceStream.ReadBuffer(len, 1);
  SetLength(TheClassName, len);
  if len > 0 then    // read GraphicClass name
    SourceStream.ReadBuffer(TheClassName[1], len);
  GraphicClass := TGraphicClass(FindClass(TheClassName)); //(*)
  if (GraphicClass <> nil) and (len > 0) then
  begin
    Graphic := GraphicClass.Create;  // create appropriate graphic class
    try
      ms2 := TMemoryStream.Create;
      try
        ms2.CopyFrom(SourceStream, SourceStream.Size - len - 1);
        ms2.Position := 0;
        Graphic.LoadFromStream(ms2);
      finally
        ms2.Free;
      end;
      Picture.Assign(Graphic);
    finally
      Graphic.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  ms: TMemoryStream;
begin
  ms := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    Picture2Stream(ms, Source.Picture);
    ms.Position := 0;
    IdTCPClient1.Host := '127.0.0.1';
    IdTCPClient1.Port := 12345;
    IdTCPClient1.Connect;
    IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.LargeStream := true;
    IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.Write(ms, ms.Size, true);
  finally
    ms.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  IdTCPServer1.DefaultPort := 12345;
  IdTCPServer1.Active := true;
  ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutDown := true;
end;

procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  ms: TMemoryStream;
begin
  ms := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    AContext.Connection.IOHandler.LargeStream := true;
    AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadStream(ms);
    TThread.Synchronize(nil,
      Procedure
      begin
        LoadPictureFromStream(Dest.Picture, ms);
      end);
  finally
    ms.Free;
  end;
end;

initialization
// RegisterClasses to enable FindClass (*)
RegisterClasses([TIcon, TMetafile, TBitmap, TJPEGImage, TPngImage]);

end.
```